# Troubleshooting compilation / .jar creation with Maven for Hadoop on Azure

Tags: java, azure, maven, hadoop

I have .Jar file with only .class files in there without any .java files...

I cloned a git repository: 
`https://github.com/kaist-dmlab/k-Medoid/tree/master/MR-KMEDIAN`

the repository has a .jar file as well, but no .pom file with the java code. So I created a Maven Project in Eclipse, created a package: `com.parallel.WEIGHTED_KMEDIAN`

and put the files in there. This is what the directory looks like:

[image]

I checked all the dependencies in the java files and looked them up on the maven website and added them. So my pom.xml file looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.parallel</groupId>
    <artifactId>WEIGHTED_KMEDIAN</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>WEIGHTED_KMEDIAN</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jpmml</groupId>
            <artifactId>pmml-model</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
<sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
   <plugins>
   <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
       <configuration>
          <release>8</release>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
   </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

When I run the .jar file on AZURE HDINSIGHTS I get an error: 
[image]

When I compared the .jar file I created and the one in the project, I am missing all the .java files.

- Is this the issue that azure doesn't like?
- How can I add the .java files in the .jar file?

I created the jar file from eclipse going into run>maven build> clean install

files in my jar:
[image]

files in jar from git repo:

[image]

so far I have tried:

1. `<sourceDirectory>src/main/java/com/parallel</sourceDirectory>`
2. Updating MAVEN project
3. clean compile install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was the project directory needed to be in a specific format, it should be under main/resources and then follow the path in the groupID specified in the POM.xml file:

[image]

POM.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.parallel</groupId>
    <artifactId>WEIGHTED_KMEDIAN</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>WEIGHTED_KMEDIAN</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jpmml</groupId>
            <artifactId>pmml-model</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
   <plugins>
   <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
       <configuration>
          <release>8</release>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
   </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

Dependencies:

[image]